# Implement a "promise always" return function

Tags: promise, bluebird

So i have these 2 functions `loadScriptWithBluebird` and `loadBluebird`, 

`loadScriptWithBluebird` is supposed to be generic for the main flow of the application, and will always return a promise.
 I wonder if it is possible with some kind of a pattern to use `loadBluebird` inside `loadScriptWithBluebird`

```
function loadBluebird(callback){
    //load the script and callback ...
    script.onload = function() {
        callback();
    };
}

function loadScriptWithBluebird (src){

    if(isBluebirdAvailable()){
        return new Bluebird(function(resolve, reject){
            //load the script and resolve ...
            script.onload = function() {
                resolve();
            };
        });
    }else{
        //issue starts here since i obviously cannot return inside the callback
        loadBluebird(function(){
            loadScriptWithBluebird(src) 
        })
    }

},
```

So the flow of the application will look like this :

```
loadScriptWithBluebird('jquery').then(function(){
    //...
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't do that, since bluebird wouldn't yet be available when you need to return the promise. So simply ignore that, and rely on the caller of your `loadScript` function to already have loaded Bluebird. There's not really a way around this.